# Prove there is a tree with $n$ vertices having degrees $d_1, d_2....d_n$

Tags: trees

For $n ≥ 2$ suppose $d_1, d_2,....d_n$ are positive integers with sum $2n - 2$. Prove there is a tree with n vertices having degrees $d_1, d_2....d_n$. I'm at a loss on this one. I'm sure it's pretty simple but I just can't get it.

Comment: Try to prove it for $n = 2$ first.

Answer (score 2):

you can use induction : it's obvious for n = 2; prove that there is at lease an $a_i = 1$ in this sequence and also there is at least one $a_i\geq 2$ and use this to fact.

P.S: since it's homework I would rather not to solve the problem but just give hints.

Comment: spelling: "at least an"

Comment: I get the induction part. What I don't get is proving the tree part.

Comment: if you get induction part: suppose for every n>m-1 a sequence with your condition is a tree. now remove the node with degree of 1 in your new sequence for m numbers and make one $d_j = d_j - 1$ now you have m-1 numbers and this numbers satisfies your condition; now add a node and connect this node to the node represent $d_j$

Comment: @MarcusPacheco sorry if I couldn't explain good in english

Answer (score 0):

Proceed along the following lines.

- First show that there exists one $d_i$ such that $d_i = 1$. Why is this true? What will happen if all the $d_j$'s are greater than $1$?
- Remove this vertex. What happens to the sum $\sum_{j \neq i} d_j$?
- Now induction to the rescue.